# How To Simplify Logic Equation

Tags: logic

Consider the logic equation below:

$$(\lnot A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land C)$$

It is already in Disjunctive Normal Form. I'm wondering if there is any way to simplify the equation further. Since $A,B,C$ are all the negations of themselves in each of the individual brackets I don't think there are any simpler ways of writing this, but I'm not sure.

If there is a more simplified version, can someone please let me know and how to reach such a simplified form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The above is not an equation; equations are logical statements of the form $e_1 = e_2$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already in its simplest form.

Generally if you write it the "arithmetic way" i.e. $$A'BC'+AB'C$$ you see that you cannot really find something nicer since you cannot factor anything.

While if was written as product of sums $$(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C')(A'+B+C)(A'+B'+C)(A'+B'+C')$$

you might think with reason that expanding it would lead to simplifications.

*Note: you can play with the software Logic Friday to evaluate these kind of expressions.*

Comment: Thanks very much!